# Managed object context does not delete all items

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a problem: not all of the items are removed from my `CoreData` managed object context on **iOS devices**. It may happen, because one of the items which are passed to the `clear()` function is not removed, and stays in the managed object context. My Swift code looks as follows:

```
func clear(items: [Item]) {
  for item in items {
    self.removeItem(id: NSUUID(uuidString: item.id)!);
  }

  do {
    try self.managedObjectContext!.save();
  } catch let error as NSError {
  }
}

func removeItem(id: NSUUID) {
  let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<ItemEntity>(entityName: self.itemEntityKey);
  fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: self.idKey + " == %@", id.uuidString);
  do {
    let result = try self.managedObjectContext!.fetch(fetchRequest);
    for resultItem in result {
      self.managedObjectContext!.delete(resultItem);
    }
  } catch let error as NSError {
  }
}
```

The code is executed in the background, when a remote notification is received during night time. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: does your fetch ever fail ?

Comment: The fetch works (as far as I can say) because the other items in the array are deleted.

Comment: save your context every operation.did you save your entity after delete?

Comment: As I wrote, I call the function clear() with a couple of items. For each item I call the function removeItem(). After all removals I save the context. Do I have to save after every single delete?

Comment: not a every single delete, after for loop you try it once.

Comment: What thread do you delete on and what thread do you save on ? what thread was the context created on ? what thread do you fetch on? - how do you know not all objects are deleted?

Comment: The item is inserted in the UI thread to the main managed object context and is saved immediately. During night time a remote notification is received and the item is being read on a background thread, processed and afterwards I want to delete it with the clear() function above. That's more or less the workflow.

It doesn't take the time (30 seconds) which a background work is assigned. It's much faster. So this should not be the problem.

I now search for the item with ==[c] and save it with a private managed object context first. Hope that helps. But it's kind of weired.